# Redirect Flow to starting record without custom controller?

Tags: visual-workflow, flow

I'm using Visual Workflow embedded in a VF page from a button on an Opp, and I want the user to be redirected back to that same Opp record when the Flow completes.  The page is using the standard Opportunity controller.

I've seen [this technique for doing the redirect](http://www.ukprogrammer.co.uk/index.php/redirect-flow-finish-location-to-new-record-detail/): 
but I'd prefer to not have to create a custom controller.

I expect there's a way to do this, given that the record exists before the Flow is run.  Could I use URLFOR [like shown here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_flows_finishlocation.htm)?  If so I'm not finding the right syntax.  Can anyone help out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out.  Quite simple.  Assuming you're starting from an opp, and the VF page uses a standard controller:

```
<flow:interview name="myFlow" finishLocation="/{!Opportunity.Id}">
```